# improve plot with 3 variables

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data.frame:

```
> dd
           V1        V2           V3
1   14.743730 1.5762030 1.820564e+05
2   11.293525 1.5616743 1.849190e+07
3    9.937889 4.2807281 5.226222e+07
4   15.483217 0.6055921 1.612945e+05
5   11.512925 0.8590718 1.653430e+07
6    9.271709 3.5639570 1.648311e+08
7   12.154779 1.0913056 7.725100e+06
8   12.254863 2.2639289 5.767500e+06
9   10.868568 1.4670616 2.142830e+07
10  12.384219 0.8867792 2.831100e+06
11  13.742940 0.3268744 1.516208e+06
12  12.315132 1.2894085 4.788700e+06
13  14.989849 0.5521075 1.768097e+05
14  11.451050 1.1676040 1.751310e+07
15  15.363073 0.6223934 1.657917e+05
16  12.899220 0.4755159 1.967226e+06
17  12.464293 0.9886397 2.086363e+06
18  12.736701 0.4495683 2.018285e+06
19   8.616858 4.5335367 2.774000e+08
20  10.950807 1.6357879 2.142830e+07
21  11.005428 2.6383457 2.044950e+07
22   9.629051 2.8459297 1.648311e+08
23  12.043554 1.6499405 9.682700e+06
24  14.914123 0.5430869 1.785336e+05
25  16.979896 0.3030517 2.360639e+04
26  13.815511 1.0962220 1.456639e+06
27  15.017750 0.4717264 1.760602e+05
28  11.849398 0.9813975 1.261910e+07
29  10.454495 3.5180136 2.338590e+07
30   9.011889 3.1449919 1.648311e+08
31   9.553930 3.5578561 1.648311e+08
32  11.608236 1.3658448 1.555550e+07
33  13.369223 1.0920776 1.762991e+06
34  11.515771 1.4969232 1.653430e+07
35   8.764053 3.9874923 2.774000e+08
36  10.122623 1.7772289 5.226222e+07
37  14.230083 1.0955896 1.022641e+06
38  10.098232 2.3853124 5.226222e+07
39  10.714418 2.3483052 2.240710e+07
40   8.969804 4.1778522 1.648311e+08
41  17.924744 0.9372727 1.354203e+04
42   7.811163 8.3438712 2.774000e+08
43  18.910904 0.6453018 6.860896e+03
44  10.839581 1.7566555 2.142830e+07
45  10.839581 1.6449275 2.142830e+07
46  13.870945 0.5644657 1.414090e+06
47  11.440355 0.8434520 1.751310e+07
48  13.923468 0.8897043 1.363032e+06
49  11.617285 1.0667866 1.555550e+07
50  11.502875 0.5134841 1.653430e+07
51  18.078190 0.3824371 1.288279e+04
52  13.304685 0.6976290 1.797030e+06
53   9.629051 4.0785583 1.648311e+08
54  17.460501 0.7800599 1.501846e+04
55  12.623137 2.2468834 2.052324e+06
56  10.982212 2.7085846 2.044950e+07
57  10.540937 3.5114572 2.240710e+07
58  13.892472 0.8788488 1.388561e+06
59  11.679287 1.4905993 1.457670e+07
60  13.785051 0.8933495 1.482169e+06
61   8.006368 6.2710499 2.774000e+08
62   9.210340 2.5349723 1.648311e+08
63  13.122363 0.6069901 1.882128e+06
64  17.359364 0.6707361 1.525865e+04
65  18.195729 0.3666130 1.230514e+04
66  11.751942 1.2659074 1.457670e+07
67  10.477288 1.5443280 2.338590e+07
68  11.517913 0.8443011 1.653430e+07
69  11.476261 2.2252419 1.751310e+07
70   9.705037 3.5185753 1.648311e+08
71  12.647548 1.3738172 2.043814e+06
72  11.231888 2.0682796 1.947070e+07
73  10.889304 3.7001075 2.142830e+07
74  12.283497 2.2255645 5.767500e+06
75  10.933107 1.2043548 2.142830e+07
76  11.881727 1.0832527 1.261910e+07
77  11.191342 1.8457868 1.947070e+07
78  16.801192 0.4532456 5.261309e+04
79  13.028931 1.5979574 1.924677e+06
80  10.668955 1.0840667 2.240710e+07
81  10.961278 2.3257595 2.044950e+07
82   8.895630 3.5105186 2.774000e+08
83  16.518106 0.4719416 8.919001e+04
84  13.334976 0.7971067 1.780011e+06
85  13.617060 1.2195412 1.609815e+06
86   9.908475 5.4032295 5.226222e+07
87   8.881836 4.5779464 2.774000e+08
88  16.603536 0.6787417 7.922130e+04
89  17.529083 0.5859315 1.484092e+04
90  15.226498 0.9309800 1.702888e+05
91  11.478334 1.6612984 1.751310e+07
92   9.257033 6.6170833 1.648311e+08
93  16.001562 0.8570780 1.343115e+05
94  14.669926 0.4920395 3.078192e+05
95  17.804495 0.4367456 1.399240e+04
96  18.292847 0.6576827 1.177319e+04
97  10.792565 2.4264054 2.142830e+07
98  15.717618 0.5619723 1.508011e+05
99  14.077875 1.1319117 1.201346e+06
100 12.007622 1.8263940 1.066150e+07
```

I would like to produce a figure that has all the three variables together.

I am currently using

```
p <- ggplot(dd, aes(V1,V2))
p + geom_point()
p + geom_point(aes(size = V3)) + scale_size_area() + theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color = 'black')) +
  xlab("V1") +
  ylab("V2")
```

to produce

[image]

However, I don't think that this is the most striking of figures. Is there another figure type that someone could suggest in order to make this figure better?

Comment: honestly. I think it is informative considering you are representing 3 continuous variables

Comment: Maybe adding a colour gradient? Also, you may want to expand your scale_size manually since it is quite concise.

Comment: You are already using V1, V2 and V3 on the same figure. Perhaps you can expand your question to make it clearer (to me)?

Comment: Are you interested in change data representation or just improve (aesthetic purposes) the example above?

Comment: `theme_classic()` saves you a few LOC

Comment: @PauloCardoso I want to know if there are any other types of figures that will highlight key features of the above graph better than a simple scatter plot, or can the scatter plot be improved (aesthetic purposes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have many options to improve that one. It's hard to tell you the way to go not knowing the purpose of this plot (publication, website, report...).

a very simple example

```
p + geom_point(aes(size = V3), shape = 21, colour = 'black',
               fill = 'blue', alpha = .5) +
  scale_size(expression('m'^3),
             range = c(3, 10),
             breaks = c(0.1, 5, 20) * 10000000,
             labels = c("low","mid", "high")) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(color = 'black')) +
  xlab("V1") +
  ylab("V2")
```

[image: plot]

or a shorter version with exactly the same outpur with this:

```
p + geom_point(aes(size = V3), shape = 21, colour = 'black',
               fill = 'blue', alpha = .5) +
  scale_size(expression('m'^3),
             range = c(3, 10),
             breaks = c(0.1, 5, 20) * 10000000,
             labels = c("low","mid", "high")) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(list(title = 'My plot\n', x = "Var1", y = 'Var2'))
```

as suggested by user @blmoore

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, a scatterplot is ideal for this kind of data. However, at this moment the points for `V1 > 15` are hardly visible. As a result it loses on information value. So, the plot can be improved on that. I also made the code a bit more compact.

The code:

```
ggplot(dd, aes(V1,V2)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=V3), shape=21, colour="black", fill="red", alpha=.5) + 
  scale_size(expression("m"^3), range = c(2, 12),
             breaks = c(0.01,3,8,15,25) * 10000000,
             labels = c("very low","low","medium","high","very high")) + 
  labs(title="Plot title\n", x="V1", y="V2") +
  theme_classic()
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Is there a method for increasing all of the points by the same scale i.e. keep the current scaling but make them all slightly bigger so that the smaller markers are more visible?

Comment: You can do that by playing with the `range = c(1, 10)` part of `scale_size`. With the first number, the size of the smallest point(s) is set. With the 2nd, the size of the largest point(s).

Comment: Great. Also, how do I change the label to read V3-label m^3 with the cubed obviously being a superscript?

Comment: Again, replace calls to `theme()` and `theme_bw()` with `theme_classic()`